# Enlazando xib con .swift

Tags: swift

Ya hice una pregunta parecida, pero está voy a enfocarla mas en lo que no entiendo. 
La duda viene de el storyboard y/o los archivos .xib enlazados con sus respectivas clases.

Cuando uno crea un controller en el storyboard, este hay que enlazarlo con su clase(que por lo que entiendo, sería su File's Owner), para así poder también crear sus outlets y actions. 
Ahora lo que me da duda, ¿porque tengo que enlazar el archivo .xib(o el viewController del storyboard) con la clase y no es al revés?

Es decir, si el objeto que se instancia es el .swift(que contiene la subclase del `UIViewController`), porque se enlaza el archivo xib a la clase y no de la forma contraria? Tiene mas lógica crear el objeto controller, y al mismo, enlazarlo con el archivo .xib

[image: Imagen del customClass]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

si lo que he entendido es por que no asignamos la vista al controller y no el controller a la vista , pues te diría que por que la lógica así lo establece.

Cuando asignas un clase a un controller del storyboard lo que le estas diciendo básicamente es quien me va a manejar o quien va ser mi dueño, al ViewController no podrías aplicarle esa regla por que la vista no maneja al controlador sino a la inversa el controlador es el que maneja a la vista.

De todas maneras tienes otras formas de por ejemplo cargar .xib sin necesidad de especificarlo en el Storyboard , te dejo un ejemplo.

```
if let menuTable = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("MenuTableView", owner: self, options: nil).first as? MenuTableView {
            let items = ["Item 1","Item 2"]
            menuTable.items = items
            self.view.addSubview(menuTable)
        }
```